# Rational Polynomial of Degree $3$ satisfying $2\cos{(2\pi/7)}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $\eta = \zeta_{7}+\bar{\zeta_{7}}$, for $\zeta_{7}=\exp{(2i\pi/7)}$. Find a polynomial of degree 3 with rational coefficients that $\eta$ satisfies.

---

I'm not so sure on how to begin by this question. I saw somewhere that a way to do this would be looking at the automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{7})$, but I don't know how to apply this hint to this situation. I as well know that $\eta=2\cos{(2\pi/7)}$, not sure if this helps though.

What would be a way to get started for this problem? I'm lost.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The number $e^{\pi i/7}$ (and its reciprocal) are roots of $x^7+1=0$, and therefore of
$$x^6-x^5+x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1=0,$$
or equivalently of 
$$(x^3+x^{-3})-(x^2+x^{-2})+(x+x^{-1})-1=0\tag{1}$$
(we divided through by $x^3$ and rearranged).

Let $t=x+x^{-1}$. Then $x^3+x^{-3}=t^3-3t$, and $x^2+x^{-2}=t^2-2$. Substitute in (1) and simplify, and we obtain our cubic equation in $t$.

Since $x=e^{\pm\pi i/7}$ are roots of (1), it follows that $t=e^{\pi i/7}+e^{-\pi i/7}$, that is, $2\cos(\pi/7)$, is a root of our cubic.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much a brute force approach:

$$\begin{align}\eta^2 &= \zeta_7^2 + 2 + \overline\zeta_7^2\\
\eta^3 &= \zeta_7^3+3(\zeta_7+\overline\zeta_7) +\overline\zeta_7^3\end{align}$$

Now remember that $\overline\zeta_7=\zeta_7^6,\overline{\zeta_7}^2=\zeta_7^5,\overline\zeta_7^3=\zeta_7^{4}$.

So: $$\eta^2+\eta^3 = 1+(\sum_{i=0}^6 \zeta_7^i) + 2\eta=1+2\eta$$

Alternatively, $\cos 2\pi/7$ is a double root of $T_7(x)-1$, where $T_7(x)$ is the seventh Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind.  Then $\cos 2\pi/7$ is a root of the GCD of $T_7(x)-1$ and $T_7'(x)$, which is $8x^3+4x^2-4x-1$. Then $2\cos2\pi/7$ is a root of $x^3+x^2-2x-1$.

Finally, you could just realize the minimal polynomial must be:

$$(x-\zeta-\zeta^6)(x-\zeta^2-\zeta^5)(x-\zeta^3-\zeta^4)$$

And that the coefficients must be integers since they are fixed by automorphisms of the original field. You can work them out - it isn't hard.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm not sure for your last approach where the minimal polynomial must be of that form. How would you come up with that? That seems less computational than the other options.

Comment: Okay, I see why this would hold. However, I'm not sure on how you can deduce that the coefficients must be integers. Perhaps because the minimal polynomial is in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?

Comment: Because if you apply any of the six automorphism of $\mathbb Q[\zeta_7]$ to the polynomial, you get the same polynomial, so the coefficients have to be in $\mathbb Q$.